# How does exp(x) keep showing up in mathematics

Tags: functions, exponential-function

When I first learnt about e, I just treated it as another number (as far as I know, it doesn't even have a natural definition), but how is it that exp(x) is so important and keeps showing up at various places in mathematics?

Comment: If you differentiate exp(x), it will remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e$ is very important because it keeps showing up in various places in mathematics.  Specifically, calculus though.

Calculus is the *study of the rate of change*, and the first time you have probably learned about the number $e$, you see how much it plays a key role in the rate of change of bank interest, or exponential growth/decay. Since calculus is the study of rate of range, $e$ is bound to appear in many aspects across calculus, whether that be derivatives, integration, polynomials, many advanced topics too like differential equations.

There is many cool properties of $e$ too.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-MZumdfbt8

[Why is the number $e$ so important in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3319/why-is-the-number-e-so-important-in-mathematics)

Answer (score 2):

One beautiful occurrence I just found out today:

Consider the equation:
$$x^y = y^x $$
$${x,y \in R^+}$$

For every positive value of x, there are two values of y that satisfy the above equation ONLY after x= e and vice versa.

To admire this amazing result, look at the graph of the equation on Desmos.

Comment: To be clear, $y=x$ is a solution for any fixed $x\in\mathbf{R}^+$. When $x>1$, $x\ne e$ there is a second $y$ that solves the equation. This follows by writing the equation as $\frac{\ln x}{x}=\frac{\ln y}{y}$ and noting that $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is strictly increasing for $x\in(0,e)$ and becomes positive for $x>1$, while it is strictly decreasing and approaches $0$ for $x\in(e,\infty)$.