# What actually is e?

Tags: calculus

Why is $e$ so special in calculus? For example: Why is the derivative of $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$  itself unlike other variables? I am just in high school (XII) so simple and detailed explanation may be preferred.

Comment: What answer do you expect to get from us that varies from information you can read about $e$ in the [wikipedia article on the number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3319/why-is-the-number-e-so-important-in-mathematics

Comment: Or, https://www.amazon.com/Story-Number-Princeton-Science-Library/dp/0691168482

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can answer this by saying that e discovered and not chosen.
$e^{x}$ is the function that has itself as a derivative. This property makes it important.
No one just decided on $e$. They discovered the value that has itself to the $x$ as a derivative and named it $e$.

Comment: Let's be a little bit careful. The derivative of any constant is 0.

Comment: $e^x$ is a function not a number