# What is logarithm & how log table can be constructed by me?

Tags: logarithms, calculator

I'm studying properties of logarithm but I don't understand how base e works. Base 10 looks simple while doing calculations of numbers having multiple of 10. As other numbers are not multiple of 10 how one can calculate without using log table. That's why I want know how log table is constructed & how base e works ?
 I'm very basic user, I don't get integration, derivatives & summations. Please give answer theoretically or using row concepts. Since I want to construct log table by myself.

Comment: I don't think this question is too broad. However, it needs a careful answer. I'll look at this tonight, if nobody has given an answer.

Comment: Essentially you want to know about the number $e$. 1:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407286/two-questions-about-eulers-number-e 2:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784022/defining-the-number-e 3:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707570/what-are-the-uses-of-eulers-number-e 4:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3319/why-is-the-number-e-so-important-in-mathematics

Comment: Is there any answer that doesn't contains integration, derivative, summation ? That's why no link is useful to me by @aditya agrawal

Comment: Logarithms were invented by Napier in 1614, almost 30 years before Newton's **birth**. So yes, basically, you can develop logarithms without analysis though it will be much more cumbersome. Analysis gives you more power to explain how they work and how to compute them efficiently, using quickly converging series instead of repeated square roots, for instance.

Comment: See representations section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: Maybe of interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698384/approximating-logs-and-antilogs-by-hand

Comment: @jean-claude atbat it helped me alot. &raised new problems about antilogs. I also wanted to do all calculations in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Logarithm" is the inverse to "exponential".  In particular, if $y= a^x$, then $log_a(y)= x$.  For example, it is true that $10^{0.30102}= 1.9999$ (approximately 2) so log(2) is approximately log(1.9999)= .30102.  If you really want to construct a table of logarithms, base 10, using paper and pencil, as mathematicians several hundred years ago, be prepared to do some tedious arithmetic (as they did)!  log(0.01) is easy- 0.01= 1/100= $10^{-2}$ so log(0.01)= -2.  log(0.02) is harder.  You can simplify a bit by arguing that log(0.02)= log(2/100)= log(2)- log(100)= log(2)- 2 so you just need to find log(2) (in fact, many tables of logarithms just give logarithms of numbers from 1 to 10).  log(2) is the x such that $10^x= 2$.  If we did not know that $10^{0.30102}$ is approximately 2, we could work it out by noting that $10^{0.3}= (10^3)^{1/10}= 1000^{1/10}$ and start calculating that value, then noting that $10^{0.4}= 10^{2/5}= 100^{1/5}$ and seeing that the first is less than 2 while the second is larger than 2- so the logarithm is between .3 and .4.  So look at $10^{3.5}$.  As I said, be prepared for so long tedious calculation.