# Why is the upper bound of Euler's number $=3$?

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

Why is the upper bound of Euler's number $=3$?

I found that the upper bound of Euler's number can be evaluated as $1 +$ the lower bound (in other word the integer part). I do not understand why is it though.

Comment: Presumably you mean the constant $e = 2.718281828\ldots$ (this is not always what is meant when people say "Euler's number"). There is no **the** upper bound. There are many upper bounds, like $3$ or $4$ or $\pi$ or $1000$ or $2.718281829$. However, depending on how you define this number, $3$ might be a comparatively easy upper bound to prove. Is that what you're asking? In that case, we need to know how you define this number.

Comment: I think so? It was one of my questions that I looked it up on the wolframalpha but have a no idea how to prove it or it is saying that the lowest integer that must be larger than the Euler's constant. If that's the case then it makes sense though

Comment: Ummm.... an upper bound on Euler's number is also $47$.  Why do you focus on $3$?  And what is the underlying point of this question?  Are you just flailing here?  Why not ask the same question about $\pi$ and $4$, say?  Or any of a dozen other mathematical constants??  Euler's constant has *some value*.  What are you really asking?

Comment: I assume the question was asking any integer that is the upper bound of e. However, the question also referring that the upper bound of E can evaluate by using the comparison test between "sum 1/n!" and "sum 1/(n(n-1))".... Now I'm really confused

Comment: Are you referring to the [ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) function? Note that the floor and ceiling of a noninteger number always differ by $1$.

Comment: I don't think so? My professor haven't used that term throughout the semester.

Comment: Do you want to prove this?
$$\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < 3
$$

Comment: I deleted the tag [tag:Eulers-constant]; I think that's a different number from the one you're asking about

Comment: It's easy to prove $e<3$ by proving instead that $\exp(-1)>1/3$ (alternating series: it's immediate that $\exp(-1)>1-1+1/2-1/6=1/3$).

Comment: ahhh I think I got what you meant by that thank you so much!

Comment: An answer I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54459/3736) provides an argument that $e$ must be between $2$ and $3$. To make this rigorous would require some effort, but if you're looking for intuition, it may help.