# Is $e$ arbitrary? If not, how is it derived?

Tags: eulers-number-e

Probably a stupid question but where did the constant $e$ come from? How did it come about? How is it derived mathematically other than $e^{i\cdot \pi} = -1$? What exactly does natural growth mean? Or is Euler's constant arbitrary?

Comment: "Where does it come from?" It comes from incredibly many places. That's the _reason_ it's an important constant.

Comment: What would it mean for $e$ to be arbitrary? Why wouldn't we just pick $e$ to be $1$ then?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/intuitive-understanding-of-the-constant-e?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: All exponents are the same, they just have different factors in the exponent to convert from one to another, meaning you can directly relate an exponent with base $a$ to an exponent with base $b$. $e$ has a special role as a result of other properties which are calculus based.

Comment: If $f(x)=a^x$ is an exponential growth function, then $f'(x)=a^x\ln a$, so it is natural to take $a=e$, and then $f'(x)=f(x)$.  Also, I changed the tag to [tag:eulers-number] from [tag:eulers-constant], which is different

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) yet?

Comment: @Somos Do you want the better answer or the honest answer?

Comment: Honesty is the best policy in general. However, MSE is supposed to be a forum to help answer people's questions. You decide if you were helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some definitions of $e$:

- The number such that $\int_1^e \frac{\mathrm d x}{x}=1$.
- $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$.
- $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

Interesting topic is to prove that all those definitions lead to the same real number.

Answer (score 1):

The number $e$ is the unique $a>0$ such that the function $f(x)=a^x$ has derivative $f'(x)=a^x=f(x).$