# Why is it correct to use sum rule for infinite series here?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, power-series, uniform-convergence

The question is about an example from [Introduction to Probability and Statistics at MIT OpenCourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/calendar/), specifically from this [document](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading4b.pdf).

[image: example part 1]
[image: example part 2]

My question is, **why can we do the highlighted transformation**? The example is about geometric distribution, so it makes sense with $p \in (0, 1)$ and later we replace $x$ with $1 - p$, so it follows that only $x \in (0, 1)$ interests us.

I tried looking up some theorems about this [on the internet](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/191229/65974) and in *Michael Spivak - Calculus*.

Here is what Spivak says about this in *Chapter 23*:
[image: Spivak - chapter 23 - theorem 3]
[image: Spivak - chapter 23 - corollary from theorem 3]

This does not seem applicable to my problem, because:

1. I have an open interval, but I can probably figure out a way around that.
2. **This is the more important point.** I don't know if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k x^{k-1}$ converges uniformly to anything, let alone if it converges to a continuous function. If I knew that, I would probably know what it converges to exactly and thus I would not need to use the sum rule.

Now about [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/191229/65974).
It contains the following theorem:

> **THEOREM 1** If the series $\sum u_k(x)$ composed of functions with continuous derivates on $[a,b]$ converges to a sum function $s(x)$ and the series $$\sum u'_k(x)$$ composed of this derivatives is majorant on $[a,b]$, then $$s'(x)=\sum u'_k(x)$$

I can't apply it here because:

1. I have open interval, not close interval.
2. $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k x^{k-1}$ is most probably not majorant on $(0, 1)$.
3. It is most probably true, that $\forall a \in (0, 1)$ this series of derivatives is majorant on $(0, a]$, **but I can't prove it**.

**TLDR: why can we use sum rule for derivating the series in first highlighted excerpt?**

Comment: https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/differentiating-power-series/