# Show that if $ f'(0)=1, f'(x)=e^x $ with the law of exponents

Tags: calculus

I'm really stuck on this one. Show that, if $f'(0)=1$ is known, one can deduce
$
f'(x)=e^x
$ with the aid of the law of exponents.
I started here and assumed that I should go towards L'hospital's rule but I get stuck after.

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}
$

The wording exactly: 
Let $f(x)=e^x$. Explain why $ f'(0)= \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$. Show that, if $f'(0)=1$ is known, one can deduce $f'(x)=e^x$ with the aid of the laws of exponents.

The first part was trivially easy but the way the problem is worded makes it seem like two separate sets of facts to deduce from.

Comment: Is there any chance that you forgot to write down the first part of this question?  As it stands, this statement is false.

Comment: There is a first question before this part to the question that assumes $f(x)=e^x$ but asks a different question. The way they worded the question makes it seem like they were separate sets of facts given as separate questions were asked, but I will probably just assume that fact in the beginning.

Comment: I updated my post to include more information.

Comment: Related: [My answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/could-you-explain-why-fracddx-ex-ex-intuitively/3043#3043) to the question ["Could you explain why $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$ 'intuitively'?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3006/409).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: To clarify for you, the problem is asking you to derive the fact that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ from the basic laws of exponents, rather than as an inherent rule of derivatives.

Given $f(x) = e^x$ we see that $f'(a) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{e^x - e^a}{x-a}$. Therefore $f'(0) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^x - e^0}{x-0} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x}$. Given that $f'(0) = 1$, we naturally see $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$.

So we now know $f(x) = e^x$ and $f'(0) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$. Use these facts to show $f'(x) = e^x$. This can be done as follows:

The general form of a derivative $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$. In this case, $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}$. By the properties of exponents, $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^xe^h-e^x}{h}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^x(e^h - 1)}{h}$.

Because the limit is with respect to $h$ (not $x$), $e^x$ is a constant, and can be pulled out of the limit such that $f'(x) = e^x \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{e^h - 1}{h}$. Substituting $h$ for $x$ in the given fact that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$ we see $f'(x) = e^x (1) = e^x$.

Comment: Usually, better to wait for clarification when the OP posts a clearly incorrect question.

Comment: I updated with the full question.

Comment: I updated with a better response.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this after no one responded for a while since I just assumed the first part of the problem went with the second. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f'(x) = x+1\neq e^x$ satisfies the condition $f'(0) = 1$, but $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{2}+x\neq e^x$. This should be thrown in the comment but I accidentally posted here.

Comment: I have already noted that inside of my answer to the problem in that exact manner. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

> Let $f(x)=e^x$. Explain why $ f'(0)= \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$. Show that, if $f'(0)=1$ is known, one can deduce $f'(x)=e^x$ with the aid of the laws of exponents.

Here's how I would parse this problem statement:

> Let $f(x)=e^x$.

This defines $f$ for all the remaining parts of the problem.

> Explain why $f'(0)= \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$.

As you already inferred, this part of the problem refers to the same $f$
that was defined at the start of the problem. You need to prove that this
equation is true. (As you noticed, this is easy.)

> Show that, if $f'(0)=1$ is known,

When you get to this part of the problem, you will have shown in the previous part of the problem that $f'(0)= \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$.
But you will not have shown that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$.
The words "if $f'(0)=1$ is known" allow you to assume this fact
without proving it; it is given to you by the problem statement.

> one can deduce $f'(x)=e^x$ with the aid of the laws of exponents.

Now that you know that $f(x)=e^x$ (by definition in the problem statement), that
$f'(0)= \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$ (already proved by you),
and that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$
(additional information given by the problem statement),
the task is to show that $f'(x) = e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

if you assume the $f(x)=a^x$ then you can show that $f'(0)=1\implies a=e$

$$f'(x)= \lim _{h \to 0}\frac{a^{(x+h)}-a^x}{h} = a^x \lim _{h \to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h} $$
So
$$ f'(0)=1 \implies \lim _{h \to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=1 $$

Now $g(a)= \lim _{h \to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$ is a perfectly well-defined function of $a$ whose inverse function is given by...

$$g^{-1}(x) = \lim _{h \to 0} (1+h x )^{1/h}$$

So 
$$ f'(0)=1 \implies g(a)=1 \implies a = g^{-1}(1) = \lim _{h \to 0} (1+h )^{1/h}=e$$

Answer (score -1):

There exist an infinite number of functions whose derivative, at x= 0, is 1. It is certainly NOT true that the derivative must be f'(x)= e^x.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why this question seemed so bogus to me. I'll just note it in my answer that you could assume $f(x)=e^x$ and the statement would hold, but there is not a way to exclude other derivatives.