# A Basic Limit From Exponentials

Tags: limits, derivatives, exponentiation

Reading the proof of exponential derivatives I understand this:

To show that $(2^x)'=\ln 2 \cdot 2^x$ in the proof is used the limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2^x-1}{x}$$

My question is: ¿How do I prove that this limit exist?

I don't care about its value. If I were going to prove that this limit is equal to
$\ln 2$, I would need the number $e$, and again, this number is defined as the number $a$ such that:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x} = 1$$

In another words if I know that for some constant value $a$ the limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x} $$

exists, let's say it's a number $L$ then I could find all the limits like these in function of $L$,
But what makes obvious that this limit exist?

Comment: I'd argue that in some sense, it *isn't* obvious that the limit exists. It requires proof. If you have L'Hopital's rule and basic properties of the exponential function that is one way to do it. If you have a power series definition of $e^x$ and facts about power series that is another way. If you don't have these things (and just have the definition of real exponentiation $a^b$ in terms of suprema of some set, or something similar) you may have to do some fiddling with inequalities (which may be equivalent to establishing properties of the exponential function $e^x$ or the number $e$).

Comment: Before proving the limit, you need to know what definition of $2^x$ you use.// What book are you reading?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm learning by 3Blue1Brown Videos (very nice) and a calculus book called Stewart. ¿Could you suggest me a book?

Comment: @user232560: which version of Stewart? Early transcendentals?

Comment: Yes, that .....

Comment: @user232560: the way Stewart proves the derivative of $b^x$ is via the chain rule and several other statements. Where are you exactly "Reading the proof of exponential derivatives"? In the book or somewhere else?

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question. The question asked it not even similar to the one in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Thanks mrsamy. Also note to users who agree with me: you can also vote to reopen this question (it is one of the options at the bottom of the question).

Comment: @AdamRubinson: The *question* in the linked duplicate is different, but the top *answer* there answers this question along the way.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: this (existence of limit of $(a^x-1)/x$ and $e$ being unique value of $a$ for which the limit is $1$) has been discussed many times here. No point of reopening.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/678361/72031) for example.

Comment: " $e$ is *defined* as the number $a$ such that:

 $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x} = 1.$$" That's interesting. How was it proven *in your book* that such a number exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a>0$ and $a\ne1$. We want to prove the existence of  $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$.

Assume that $r>1$ and let $f(x)=x^r-rx+r-1$ for $x>0$. Then

$$f'(x)=r(x^{r-1}-1)\begin{cases}<0 &\text{if }0<x<1\\
=0 &\text{if }x=1\\
>0 &\text{if }x>1 \end{cases}$$

Therefore, $f$ attains its absolute minimum at $x=1$. So  for all $x>0$, we have

$$f(x)\ge f(1)=0$$

$$x^r\ge rx+1-r$$

So when $r>1$ and $h>0$, $\displaystyle\frac{a^{rh}-1}{rh}\ge\frac{ra^h+1-r-1}{rh}$ and hence

\begin{align}
\frac{a^{rh}-1}{rh}-\frac{a^h-1}{h}\ge0
\end{align}

When $r>1$ and $h<0$, $\displaystyle\frac{a^{rh}-1}{rh}\le\frac{ra^h+1-r-1}{rh}$ and hence

\begin{align}
\frac{a^{rh}-1}{rh}-\frac{a^h-1}{h}\le0
\end{align}

Therefore, $\displaystyle \frac{a^h-1}{h}$ is an increasing function in $h$. As it is bounded below by $0$ on $(0,\infty)$, $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$ exists.

When $h<0$,

$$\frac{a^h-1}{h}=a^h\left(\frac{a^{-h}-1}{-h}\right)$$

As $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0^-}a^h$ exists and equals $1$, $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$ exists and $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{a^h-1}{h}= \lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$ exists.

Source: [How does one prove that $e$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312038/how-does-one-prove-that-e-exists)

Comment: vitamin d, That's the proof i was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

$${{2^x-1}\over x}={{e^{xln(2)}-1\over x}}$$

$$\ln(2){{e^{x\ln(2)}-1\over {\ln(2)x}}}$$

Use the variable change $u=\ln(2)x$.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea but that metod uses that: